# Params passed into URL Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, parameters

I'm having some issue with my `form_tag` search functionality is not redirecting me properly to a place where I can see the results of my search.
It was working fine yesterday, Once the submit button of the search is clicked, a `get` request to the `pets` controller `search` method is fired and then I was redirected to the `results.html.erb` page where the results are displayed.

The problem is that now when I submit the search, it's just refreshing the page (`index.html.erb`) and my params are passed to the URL but none of the "pets" i searched for are displayed.

```
http://localhost:3000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=iDXugIhTyjknCMpPh2P5x7voNMSQ3Y7Aa1HIZPA7xqZ9Oj4CAuVc5eJPqfE1CLwxXAsCebgPuNWqpOk381TlvQ%3D%3D&pets%5Bzip_code%5D=10019&pets%5Bspecies%5D=Cat&pets%5Bbreed%5D=&pets%5Bage%5D=&pets%5Bsex%5D=&pets%5Bsize%5D=&commit=Find+Pets%21
```

Before it was just redirecting me the results page `localhost:3000/results`

Here is my ***pets*** controller

```
class PetsController < ApplicationController



  def index #index page will render search form
    @pet = Pet.new
    #send form data in params to create
  end


  def search
    @pets = Pet.where(clean_params)
    render :results
  end

  private

  def thinned_params
    params["pets"].delete_if {|k, v| v.empty?}
  end

  def clean_params
    thinned_params.permit(:species, :zip_code, :sex, :size, :breed, :age)
  end

end
```

My `form_tag` in welcome#index:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<%= form_tag :controller => 'pets', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>
 <%= label_tag('pets[zip_code]', "Zipcode") %>
 <%= text_field_tag('pets[zip_code]') %>
 <%= label_tag('pets[species]', "Type") %>
 <%= select_tag('pets[species]', options_for_select([["Dog","Dog"],["Cat","Cat"],["Rabbit", "Rabbit"], ["Small & Furry","Smallfurry"],["Horse", "Horse"],["Pig", "Pig"],["Reptile", "Reptile"],["Bird", "Bird"],["Barnyard", "Barnyard"]])) %>
  <%= label_tag('pets[breed]', "Breed") %>
  <%= text_field_tag('pets[breed]', nil, class: 'typeahead') %>
  <%= label_tag('pets[age]', "Age") %>
  <%= select_tag('pets[age]', options_for_select([["None",""],["Baby","Baby"],["Young","Young"],["Adult", "Adult"], ["Senior","Senior"]])) %>
  <%= label_tag('pets[sex]', "Gender") %>
  <%= select_tag('pets[sex]', options_for_select([["None",""],["Male","M"],["Female","F"]])) %>
    <%= label_tag('pets[size]', "Size") %>
  <%= select_tag('pets[size]', options_for_select([["None",""],["Small","S"],["Medium","M"], ["Large", "L"], ["Xtra Large", "XL"]])) %>

 <%= submit_tag "Find Pets!" %>
 <%end%>
</form>
```

And finally...my ***routes.rb***

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  # resources :pets

  root 'welcome#index'

  get '/pets' => 'pets#index'

  post '/pets/search' => 'pets#search'

  resources :favorite_pets

  get '/my_pets' => 'users#my_pets'
end
```

So my question is why is my params passed to the URL when it should just hit the `search` method in the `pets` controller and redirect me to the results page displaying the info?
Second question, obviously, what can I do to fix this problem?

***UPDATE***
here is the output of my console when the "search" button is clicked.

```
Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=NgVe%2Fe5i6sn8ijRmgcvOezp62KlymrNRWPJfFNOVJ54ChWpZf8JYTm%2Fk%2FeHdDsvcgzdBYe%2BjUX5jiz2JeALEpQ%3D%3D&pets%5Bzip_code%5D=10019&pets%5Bspecies%5D=Cat&pets%5Bbreed%5D=&pets%5Bage%5D=&pets%5Bsex%5D=&pets%5Bsize%5D=&commit=Find+Pets%21" for ::1 at 2015-03-15 15:54:34 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NgVe/e5i6sn8ijRmgcvOezp62KlymrNRWPJfFNOVJ54ChWpZf8JYTm/k/eHdDsvcgzdBYe+jUX5jiz2JeALEpQ==", "pets"=>{"zip_code"=>"10019", "species"=>"Cat", "breed"=>"", "age"=>"", "sex"=>"", "size"=>""}, "commit"=>"Find Pets!"}
  Pet Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "pets".* FROM "pets"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "pets".* FROM "pets"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "pets".* FROM "pets"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "pets".* FROM "pets"
  Breed Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "breeds".* FROM "breeds" INNER JOIN "pet_breeds" ON "breeds"."id" = "pet_breeds"."breed_id" WHERE "pet_breeds"."pet_id" = ?  [["pet_id", 71]]
  Shelter Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "shelters".* FROM "shelters" WHERE "shelters"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 26]]
  Breed Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "breeds".* FROM "breeds" INNER JOIN "pet_breeds" ON "breeds"."id" = "pet_breeds"."breed_id" WHERE "pet_breeds"."pet_id" = ?  [["pet_id", 73]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "shelters".* FROM "shelters" WHERE "shelters"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "26"]]
  Breed Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "breeds".* FROM "breeds" INNER JOIN "pet_breeds" ON "breeds"."id" = "pet_breeds"."breed_id" WHERE "pet_breeds"."pet_id" = ?  [["pet_id", 41]]
  Shelter Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "shelters".* FROM "shelters" WHERE "shelters"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  Breed Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "breeds".* FROM "breeds" INNER JOIN "pet_breeds" ON "breeds"."id" = "pet_breeds"."breed_id" WHERE "pet_breeds"."pet_id" = ?  [["pet_id", 9]]
  Shelter Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "shelters".* FROM "shelters" WHERE "shelters"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (20.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 127ms (Views: 125.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

***Rake Routes***
https://slack-files.com/files-pub/T02MD9XTF-F041PKBE2-532b801cb1/-.txt

Comment: Why does index create a new pet?

Comment: Index and search should be one action (index), now that I look at it.

Comment: Please post the output of your web server logs from when you make the request. The logs will tell you what the server thinks you are asking for and what it is trying to tell the browser.

Comment: [@Beartech](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2727267/beartech) Here you go, check the update

Comment: OK how about the results of `rake routes` on the command line? See what routes are actually generated.

Comment: Also, any time you change your routes you need to restart your web server to have them take effect. You are using GET in the form tag but you have Post defined in your routes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your routes file, the search action only accepts POST (not GET):

```
post '/pets/search' => 'pets#search'
```

That seems appropriate, so just change your form action to use the POST method:

```
form_tag :controller => 'pets', :action => 'search', :method => :post
```

Comment: Not exactly, you are more of `GET`ting a list of pets, not updating or replacing pets.

Comment: You are posting a bunch of form variable.  Unless you want all that crap in the URL, use POST.

Comment: Not exactly, you should look [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), and see what they mean

Comment: "The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process."

Comment: "The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is designed to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:"

Comment: So I tried both of your solutions but none of them worked im still getting the params passed to the url and the page index page is just reloading (when it should redirect me to the results page with all the pets I searched for displayed there)

Comment: If you want to use GET, just change your route.

Comment: If you use GET, your params will always show up in the URL. There is no way around that.  If you don't want the params in the URL use POST.  Whichever way you choose just make sure that the route for pets#search and the form method use the same method.

Comment: There is no reason to avoid params in the URL for a search unless you personally don't like it. Those params are still there, even if using a POST and you just don't see them. It is no more secure. I can as easily use Chrome to make post requests where I change the params being submitted to what ever I want. That's why we have Strong Parameters, to prevent that from being an attack vector.

Comment: Not only that but the real problem is that it's not even rendering the "results" page with the appropriate "pets" I searched for.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is `POST`, but that makes no sense, are you trying to update or replace pets? No, you getting a list of pets. You are already calling a `GET` request in your form, so you can leave that, and change
`post '/pets/search' => 'pets#search'` to `get '/pets/search' => 'pets#search'`

More [information on get and post](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: take a look at my comment on infused answer. tried both solutions, still the same problem... :(

Comment: right, it is, I totally agree with you on that. Convention over configuration :)